# Local storage data persisted after logout

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, local-storage

I'm building a React web app. It stores a token in localstorage after user login through a 3rd party Oauth2 service.

When an user logout, localstorage.clear() did cleared the token.

`Storage {length: 0}`

However, if I click the brower's back button a couple of times, I'm back in the app, the token re-appear in local storage like I've never logout before.

I've tried:

`localstorage.clear(), localStorage.removeItem('accessToken'), location.reload(true) ...`

How can I clear out the storage and history?

Comment: Did you try to check localstorage contents in the console? If you clear localstorage, you clear it. There's no evidence that wasn't cleared. There's no evidence that it wasn't re-added for some reason. The problem totally depends on your case and requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This sounds like the browser is showing a cached page, not restoring the local storage.

Comment: You probably should use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`, although I don't think it will resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how this service stores the token in localstorage, however it seems weird. Since it's local storage it has to be set by javascript code that was loaded part of the page. When you go back the browser can easily load the page from the cache, and executes javascript which sets the local storage again. Again, storing login tokens in local storage is kind of weird.

Comment: I've tried sessionStorage and cookies... no help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of getting back the localstorage value once you `clear/removeItem`. I'm guessing you're using redux and storing your token somewhere in the store. When you click back, at some point you are probably saving it to the localstorage again.